# Can the $1$-skeleton of a cube cover the $1$-skeleton of a tetrahedron?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

As the title suggest, I'm trying to figure out whether the $1$-skeleton of a cube can cover the $1$-skeleton of a tetrahedron.

A quick look at Euler Characteristic suggests that the only possibility is that the "cube" (I will omit $1$-skeleton) can only **double** cover the tetrahedron.

Looking at the fundamental groups we have an injection of the free group on $5$ generators into the free group on $3$ generators which is not impossibile.

Is there a way to exhibit explicit covering or to prove its non-existence?

Comment: Yes it covers. If you start at a vertex of the cube and work out, it should be pretty easy to come up with a covering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Double cover] $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $